# Parsing XML request

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm very very new to being on the Server side of things. I need to set up a simple server.php to receive xml requests.

I'm not even sure how to start with this.  I am used to the normal Post/Get variables from forms.

Here's an example of what I'm listening for, and needing to respond to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <authenticate xmlns="http://someplace.someplace.com/">
            <strUserName xsi:type="xsd:string">username</strUserName>
            <strPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">password</strPassword>
        </authenticate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Obviously there's a username/password I can see inside.
Validating the user/pass is the easy part, but how do I parse that out?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use DOM element to access your desired values:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <authenticate xmlns="http://someplace.someplace.com/">
            <strUserName xsi:type="xsd:string">username</strUserName>
            <strPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">password</strPassword>
        </authenticate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

$username = $dom->getElementsByTagName('strUserName')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$password = $dom->getElementsByTagName('strPassword')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: question, you put the actual xml inside the $xml var.
If server.php is listening, is it a $_POST?  How do I put the request into the $xml?

Comment: Depends on the request, but yes, it will be  `post` or `get` value. Just find out, witch value contains the request and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with SimpleXML, you have a few examples here:

[SimpleXML examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use existing API when parsing a SOAP request. This will not only automatically get rid of your parsing problems but also generate correct SOAP output.

Example:

```
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <authenticate xmlns="http://someplace.someplace.com/">
            <strUserName xsi:type="xsd:string">foo</strUserName>
            <strPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">bar</strPassword>
        </authenticate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$s = new SoapServer(NULL, array('uri' => 'http://someplace.someplace.com/'));
$s->setClass("Auth");
$s->handle($request);

class Auth
{
    public function authenticate($strUserName, $strPassword)
    {
        return "U: $strUserName; P: $strPassword";
    }
}
```

**Note**: If you do not pass an argument to `handle()` it will use `POST` data.